# Jest error: Mongoose: looks like you're trying to test a Mongoose app with Jest's default jsdom test environment

Tags: express, mongoose, jestjs

Testing with Jest endpoint of ExpressJS with Mongoose middleware I came across with the following error:

```
Mongoose: looks like you're trying to test a Mongoose app with Jest's default jsdom test environment. Please make sure you read Mongoose's docs on configuring Jest to test Node.js apps: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/jest.html
```

What is the issue?

Answer (score 12):

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest --testEnvironment=node --verbose --forceExit --watchAll --maxWorkers=1"
 }
```

1. add --testEnvironment=node to package.json as shown above.
2. Then re-run "npm test"

Issue Resolved!

Answer (score 8):

According to official [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/jest.html) for Mongoose you need to solve this problem by creating `jest.config.js` with the following content:

```
module.exports = {
  testEnvironment: 'node'
};
```

And guess what? It has solved my issue pretty painlessly :-)